# .gitignore is not ignoring untracked files

Tags: git

I don't understand why my `.gitignore` file is not working as intended. It is added to my repo. It fails to ignore the `__pycache__` subfolders as well as the `test.xyz` I added to test the `.gitignore` functionality.

`.gitignore` Contents:

```
__pycache__/
src/__pycache__
*.py[cod]
*.csv
**/*.pyc
*.pyc
*.xlsx
*.xyz
```

What happens when I run `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/__pycache__/
        tst.xyz

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Please advise.

Edit:
Here's the folder structure:

```
repo/
 |
 | src/
 |  | __pycache__/
 |
 | tests/
 |
 | .gitignore
 | LICENSE
```

Comment: Is your `.gitignore` in utf-8 or in some other encoding?

Comment: Is your .gitignore file in repository root and can git read it?

Comment: @Roman I did the basic `touch .gitignore` to create it. Is more required than that?

Comment: @blami yes. it is in the root of my repo.

Comment: Did you previously commit any of the files you are now trying to ignore?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, they were never committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes to .gitignore file, you ought to do the following

```bash
# git commit -m "before updating gitignore"
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore updated"
```

To test it, try modifying any of the ignored files, run `git status` and you'll have nothing to commit (working tree clean).